# Changes in apache2.conf not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My websites are hosted in separate folders inside the www directory

That would be 
www/site1
www/site2
www/site3
etc.

I have added the following command inside the  block, however, it does not seem to be working.

```
<Directory /home/www/>
        Options -Indexes -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        RewriteEngine on
        ModPagespeed on
        ExpiresActive on
</Directory>
```

For example, the URL rewriting does not work if I do not had "RewriteEngine on" in an htaccess file, which does not make sense to me as "RewriteEngine on" has been added to the config file.
Basically, the url rewriting does not work in the websites added in the www subfolders despite the fact that the command has been added properly to the config file.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your help

Comment: `RewriteEngine on` needs be added in .htaccess file also, having it in server config doesn't make it available for all the .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have disabled the multiviews.

```
<Directory /home/www/>
   Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   ModPagespeed on
   ExpiresActive on
</Directory>
```

Thats enough normally you have default settings and that should work.